# Documentation in ember.js repo

Tags: javascript, ember.js, documentation

I want to contribute to ember.js and want to make a PR for these two issues.

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/20102
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/19896

However, I am not able to find the documentation in the repo. My assumption is that the documentation is built from the source files. Could anyone please guide me on what should I be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for wanting to contribute!

For both issues, the docs are generated from code

`deprecate`'s docs live here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/16136bfcb6a0242d9c55ca7023ab8ea317167c71/packages/%40ember/debug/lib/deprecate.ts#L192

though, I don't know why there is a mismatch between what is shows on the api docs site, here: https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.4/functions/@ember%2Fdebug/deprecate
verses what is in the code.

For `transitionTo`, the docs are generated from here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/b81e32407b9ed0191cb4d09dcfce9825db320570/packages/%40ember/-internals/routing/lib/services/router.ts#L75

If you have more questions, hoppin in to the Ember.JS Discord, https://discord.gg/emberjs and joining #dev-ember-learning (or just #general) channels can help you out as you run in to issues or have questions. (you can usually also ping the issue reporter as well for more context)